# MVVM DataTrigger don't work

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I have the following code

```
<DockPanel.Style>
            <Style TargetType="DockPanel">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=flowTreeView, Path=SelectedItem.hasInput}" Value="1" >
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=txtBoxPopUp}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=flowTreeView, Path=SelectedItem.hasInput}" Value="0" >
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </DataTrigger>              
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DockPanel.Style>
```

Before my question, this app has a TreeView with some nodes. When i select a node that requires user input, it shows the previous DockPanel. The DockPanel also contains a **StackPanel** below the DockPanel.Style.

As you can see, this **DockPanel** starts with **Visibility=Hidden**. Then, when the trigger fires where **SelectedItem.hasInput** has the **value=1**, it sets the Visibility of the DockPanel to **Visible** and it's supposed to focus my TextBox **txtBoxPopUp**. The problem is when i click the node, nothing happens(does not show the DockPanel). But if i remove the second Setter(which give focus to TextBox), the DockPanel appears normally. Other strange behavior, with the 2 Setters, if i click several times the Node that requires user input it brings the DockPanel with the TextBox focused, but is happens only sometimes.

Conclusion, i want to focus the TextBox when the DockPanel it's visible, but i am not able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Style TargetType="DockPanel">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=flowTreeView, Path=SelectedItem.hasInput}" Value="1" >
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=txtBoxPopUp}"/>          
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You do not need to have the second data-trigger (setting to `Hidden`). Since this is already the default value, there's no need to have it.

Comment: Before all, thanks for the answer. Do you mean TargetName? If so, the TextBox name is not recognized.

Comment: Actually, you don't need it. I updated the code. try it now :D

Comment: so you just removed the DataTrigger to set the visibility to hidden right? but it does not work either :(